# Asp.net MVC-fileupload value shows null values in httppost method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On the View:

```html
<div id="project-contact-form">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Apply","Careers", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onApplySuccess" }, new { @id = "form1", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="success-project-contact-form" class="no-margin-lr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" required name="Firstname" id="Firstname" placeholder="First name" class="big-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" required name="Lastname" id="Lastname" placeholder="Last name" class="big-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" required name="Email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="big-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" required name="Mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="big-input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    
                        <input type="file" name="FileUploader" id="files" class="hidden" />
                        <label for="files" class="float-left cursor-pointer">Upload CV</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button id="project-contact-us-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-transparent-bnsights btn-rounded md-margin-15px-bottom sm-display-table sm-margin-lr-auto">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }

            </div>
```

In the Controller:   `HttpPostedFileBase FileUploader` value= null i tried several ways but don't know the reason why it is null

```
 public ActionResult Apply(ContactUsModel model, HttpPostedFileBase FileUploader)
    {
        SendEmail sendemail = new SendEmail();

        string toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactUsEmail"];

        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Firstname", model.Firstname },
            { "Lastname", model.Lastname },
            { "Email", model.Email },
            { "Orgnization", model.Orgnization },
            { "Message", model.Message }
        };

        // string body = $"Firstname : {model.Firstname} \n Lastname : {model.Lastname}\n Email : {model.Email} \n Orgnization : {model.Orgnization} \n Message : {model.Message}";
        if (keys != null && keys.Count != 0)
        {
            string body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, keys.Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}"));

            sendemail.Send(new EmailModel()
            {
                Body = body,
                Subject = "Contact Us Message",
                To = new List<string>() { toEmail },


            }, FileUploader);

            return Json(new { val = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { val = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }          
    }
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you cannot upload file using `Ajax.BeginForm()` like `Html.BeginForm()`. You have to use JavaScript/jQuery to submit the form element.

Here is the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("submit", "#form1", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            var url = this[0].action;

            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                  //do necessary work with response
                }
              },
              error: function() {
                //handle error here
              },
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false
            });
            return false;
          });
});
```

Comment: can you give an example with my code please to be clear for for ?

Comment: but i want to understand why can not using Ajax.BeginForm() or Html.BeginForm()

Comment: yes but why its not working with Ajax.BeginForm() or Html.BeginForm()